# Select new in Linq based on condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm absolutely a noob at Linq and I'd like if the task I'm trying to do is possible using Linq. I'm currently trying to create objects from an XML file, and trying to populate a list which should accept different classes (polymorphism).

So I'm trying to achieve something like this... 
I have a XML document like this:

```
<Quiz>
<Questions>
    <Question number='1' type='Simple' bone='Tibia'>
        <Choices>
            <Choice label='A'>This is choice A.</Choice>
            <Choice label='B'>This is choice B.</Choice>
            <Choice label='C'>This is choice C.</Choice>
            <Choice label='D'>This is choice D.</Choice>
        </Choices>
        <Answer label = 'A'/>
    </Question>
    <Question number='1' type='Complex' bone='Fibula'>
        <Choices>
            <Choice label='A' region='x'>This is choice A.</Choice>
            <Choice label='B' region='x'>This is choice B.</Choice>
            <Choice label='C' region='x'>This is choice C.</Choice>
            <Choice label='D' region='x'>This is choice D.</Choice>
        </Choices>
        <Answer label = 'A'/>
    </Question>
</Quiz>
```

And my code looks like this...

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@filename);
  List<Question> Questions =  (from e in xml.Root.Elements("Question")
                               if (string)e.Attribute('type').Equals('Simple') // Something like this condition
                               select new SimpleQuestion 
                               {
                                 Bone = (string)e.Attribute('bone'),
                                 Answer = (string)e.Elements('Answer').Attribute('label'),
                                 // do something
                               }
                               if (string)e.Attribute('type').Equals('Complex') // Or this condition
                               select new ComplexQuestion
                               {
                                 // do something
                               }
                              ).ToList();
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have if statements or conditionals in a way which will allow me to select different types of objects. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a complex sample?

Comment: Write a method that returns `Question` and takes the type. Then call it in the LINQ query

Comment: Your doubt is if it is possible? Why did not tried yet?

Comment: I've updated the xml jdweng (I'm still considering the design. The classes differ mainly in terms of functionality, not fields.) 
@TimSchmelter Thanks! That's very resourceful. I've been pouring over documentation, and I'd love it if you could give me a small example. 
Adolfok3 I tried and failed lol.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use dictionaries to parse xml like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var dict = doc.Descendants("Question")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("number"), y => new {
                      type = (string)y.Attribute("type"),
                      bone = (string)y.Attribute("bone"),
                      answer = (string)y.Element("Answer").Attribute("label"),
                      choices = y.Descendants("Choice").GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("label"), b => new KeyValuePair<string,string>((string)b.Attribute("region"),(string)b))
                          .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault())
                }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => (object)y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
}
```